# Office Open XML: Relationship not used in the document

Tags: standards, openxml, relationship

I have an Open Office XML document where a relationship that is defined in a relationship part is not used anywhere in the document, neither in the MainDocumentPart nor in any other part. Is this an invalid OpenXML Documment or not. Are unsues relationships allowed do the cause the document to be invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem to cause any problems.